# How to convert Base64 data and NSData into string

Tags: ios, swift, base64, nsdata, pdf-viewer

i am new in IOS and i am making a project in which i receive Base64 data from web service. how to convert Base64 data into string and how to open a pdf view in swift and also check that is there any pdf owner application install or not in iPhone .and i want to know that how to convert NSDATA in string swift.Help me
example like this is Base64 data
JVBERi0xLjQKJcfsj6IKNSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNiAwIFIvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZT4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nLVcza8ct5GH1rK9ejIU24lkO5GtJ8vWm5E87eY3uXtbYLHAYi8JdItySrABAjhA8v8fUuwmu35kF2fmxbsWDMxjk8VisapYX+TfbudJ6ds5/6s//vj

Like this is nsdata
<25504446 2d312e34 0a25c7ec 8fa20a35 2030206f 626a0a3c 3c2f4c65 6e677468 20362030 20522f46 696c7465 72202f46 6c617465 4465636f 64653e3e 0a737472 65616d0a 789cb55c cdaf1cb7 9187d6b2 bd7a3214 db89643b 91ad27cb d69b913c

Answer (score 5):

There are two parts to this question. First, converting the base 64 string into a `Data`/`NSData`. But you've done that already, so you don't need help there.

Second, converting that `Data`/`NSData` into a string. But, if you look at that file carefully, you'll see that data is a PDF file, not a text string. For example, if I save that as a file and look at it in a hex editor, I can clearly see it's a PDF:

[image: hex dump]

You can't just convert that PDF binary data to a string. (In fact, that's why it was base64-encoded in the first place, because it was complex binary data.)

But you can, for example, use [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller) to preview the PDF file that you saved to a file.

---

For example:

```
// convert base 64 string to data

let base64 = "JVBERi0xLjQKJcfsj6IKNSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNiAwIFIvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZT4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nLVcza8ct5GH1rK9ejIU24lkO5GtJ8vWm5E87eY3uXtbYLHAYi8JdItySrABAjhA8v8fUuwmu35kF2fmxbsWDMxjk8VisapYX+TfbudJ6ds5/6s/"
guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64) else {
    print("unable to convert base 64 string to data")
    return
}

// given the data was PDF, let's save it as such

let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("test.pdf")
try! data.write(to: fileURL)

// if it was a string, you could convert the data to string, but this will fail
// because the data is a PDF, not a text string
//
// guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
//     print("Unable to convert data into string")
//     return
// }
// print(string)

// So, instead, let's use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to preview the PDF:

let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: fileURL)
controller.delegate = self
controller.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

Where, the view controller conforms to `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`:

```
extension ViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self

        // or, if this view controller is already in navigation controller, don't 
        // return `self`, like above, but instead return the navigation controller itself
        //
        // return navigationController!
    }

}
```

Comment: When you do `Data(base64Encoded:)`, that will convert the string to a data. And that _is_ a PDF which you can save to a file, if you're so inclined. See example in revised answer. Clearly, you only shared an excerpt of your base64 payload, so the above won't save the whole PDF, but if you repeat this with the original full base64 payload, it should work fine.

Comment: but this code prints Unable to convert data into string

Comment: it also prints this for my Base64

Comment: That’s my entire point. The data represented by that base 64 string was not, itself, a string. It’s a PDF, which is a binary file, not a string. I was just showing you how to display it as a string _if it was a string in the first place, but it wasn’t._ But I I showed you how to save that as a PDF file in case you wanted to the open it up in a PDF viewer, for example.

Comment: @rachnasharma - If you want to view the PDF, you have to fire up a PDF viewer, such as the `UIDocumentInteractionController`. See revised code snippet above.

Answer (score 3):

From `Base64` to `Data` to `String`.

```
let base64String = "dGhpcyBpcyBmb3IgdGVzdGluZw=="
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
    if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(string)
    }
}
```

From `Base64` to `NSData` to `String`.

```
let data = NSData(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    var string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

Comment: if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
    var string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}

Comment: Check my edited answer. It works if your base64 data is correctly encoded.

Comment: i checked it and it works well but when i try it with my Base64 string it gives again nil while unwrapping

Comment: @Lawliet when I am trying to Base64 string am getting nil value  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768556/decode-from-base64-format-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

A handy extension of string. Hope will help you.

```
extension String {

    func fromBase64() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else {
            return nil
        }

        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }

    func toBase64() -> String {
        return Data(self.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```