# Decode from Base64 format in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I am trying to Decode the encrypt key. I tried decode online I am getting bellow result 
it was working.

```
KEY : oPvvNMsiOd//bheeboamB65AXi8r+go9NLz2rTPEJRU=
decode values : 4"9nn@^/+
=43%
```

when I tried this code it was getting fatal error

```
let base64Encoded = "oPvvNMsiOd//bheeboamB65AXi8r+go9NLz2rTPEJRU="
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded)!
let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(decodedString)
```

I tried many ways, I have to Decode from the base64.

Comment: What is the problem ? its not working, like wrong value or just wont compile or other stuff ?

Comment: @MohmmadS am getting fatal error  when I tried I need to get this 4"9nn@^/+

Comment: The decoded data is not a valid UTF-8 string ...

Comment: @Martin thankq for replay, how can I convet in to string

Comment: When I am trying in to the web I am getting the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found solution for my issue am getting exact out put.

```
    extension Character {
        var isAscii: Bool {
            return unicodeScalars.allSatisfy { $0.isASCII }
        }
    }
    extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
        var asciiPrintable: Self {
            return filter { $0.isAscii }
        }
    }
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let base64Encoded = "oPvvNMsiOd//bheeboamB65AXi8r+go9NLz2rTPEJRU="
            let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded, options: [])
            var decodedString: String? = nil
            if let decodedData = decodedData {
                decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .ascii)
                print(decodedString)
                let ascivalue = decodedString!.asciiPrintable
                print(ascivalue)
            }
        }
        }

Output: 

Optional(" ûï4Ë\"9ßÿn\u{17}n¦\u{07}®@^/+ú\n=4¼ö­3Ä%\u{15}")

4"9nn@^/+
=43%
```